# How to disable vertical scrolling while horizontal scrolling is in progress using the trackpad on a Macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, macos

Macbook trackpad allows both vertical and horizontal scrolling. But when I try to do horizontal scrolling, some vertical scrolling also taking place unintentionally (may be my finger movements are no so precious) which annoys me.

Is there a way to disable vertical scrolling while horizontal scrolling is in progress? If there is no built in way in macOS to do this, are there any third party extensions to do this job?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're doing when this is a problem? In my experience, the Trackpad generally favours one direction or the other, allowing some latitude before changing direction. I can draw quite a diagonal line too, and it will still go straight. There are preferences for the Trackpad in the Accessibility system preference pane that control the Scrolling Speed, as well as the settings from Tracking Speed in the Trackpad's own preference pane. Maybe if you slow it down it will respond better, allowing you a greater degree of control.

Comment: If the trackpad generally favors one direction or the other, then no problem at all, this is what I want, and you are lucky. But this does not seem to be the case in my side. I am using macOS Mojave on 2017 Macbook Air, what is your Macbook?

Comment: This is my experience on several different MacBook Airs, MacBook Pros and Magic Trackpads. Is it likely you've changed the Trackpad default settings before this? Have you tried reducing the Scroll and Tracking Speeds?

Comment: I have the same issue, I can scroll "circle" on Chrome, MySQL Workbench, and perhaps a bunch of other app. I'm currently on a Macbook pro 15 2017 - Mojave